# How do I display a backbone collection using a view?

Tags: backbone.js, laravel

I'm working on a simple booking system using BackBone with Laravel as the RESTful API.

I'm new to BackBone so just need some advice on how things piece together.

The system will require a user to select a track, date and event type and be presented with how many places are remaining.

So far, my (very simple) backbone app looks like this:

**Model**

```
 CalEvent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'ID',
    defaults: {
      ID: '',
      EventID: '',
      CircuitID: '',
      StartTime: '',
      EventFormatID: '',
      TotalPlaces: '',
      BookedPlaces: '',
      ProvisionalPlaces: ''
    },
    url: '/tracker/booking'
  });
```

**Collection**

```
   var CalEvents = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model : CalEvent
});

var calEvents = new CalEvents;

var search_params = {
  'CircuitID': 53,
  'EventFormatID': 224,
  'StartTime': '2014-11-04'
};

calEvents.fetch({
  data: $.param(search_params),
  success: function (cal) {
          _.each(cal.models, function(model) {
            console.log(model.toJSON());
          })
       },
       error: function(model, xhr, options)
       {
         console.log(xhr);
       }
});
```

So far, so good. This connects to the laravel app passing the data and returns JSON objects for each of the events:

```
{ID: 18, EventID: 155957, CircuitID: 53, StartTime: "2014-11-04 17:15:00", EventFormatID: 224, RemainingPlaces: 18}
```

What I need is that when a user selects a date, track and event type, this data will be collected, passed to the laravel app and the data then presented to the user (specifically the RemainingPlaces).

I'm struggling to understand how the View part of BackBone can 'listen' to events (ie the user selecting their options), call the collection with the data and then rendering it on screen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**update**

I've created the following view:

```
var CalView = Backbone.View.extend({
el : $(".booking"),
initialize: function(){
    this.EventID = this.model.get('EventID');
    console.log('thingy'+this.EventID);
},
events: {
    'click' : 'clickHandler'
},
clickHandler:function(evt){

  var search_params = 
  {
    'CircuitID': 53,
    'EventFormatID': 224,
    'StartTime': '2014-11-05'
  };

  this.collection.fetch({
  data: $.param(search_params),
  success: function (cal) {
          _.each(cal.models, function(model) {
            //console.log(model.toJSON());
          })
       },
       error: function(model, xhr, options)
       {
         //console.log(xhr);
       }
  });

  this.render();
},
render:function(){
     console.log('render');   
    _.each(this.collection.models, function (m, i, l) { 
        console.log('Booked Places: '+m.get('TotalPlaces'));           
    });
}
```

});

The search Params will be determined based on the users click and passed to the collection.fetch() function.

Is this the correct way to do it??

One issue I've noticed is when I click the element, the first few times no results are returned (with no error message). After 3 or 4 clicks, the results are returned and displayed in the console.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include your view? There are different ways to listen for/trigger events in Backbone views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't currently have a view written....I'm not sure exactly where/how to start! Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of a basic model and view. Working on refitting to make use of a collection [http://jsfiddle.net/oakley349/ate0Lpos/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/oakley349/ate0Lpos/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Based on the fiddle I've created a view (updated in main question). Is the way I'm fetching the results within the click function the correct way to do it? Thanks again

Comment: Here's and example of rendering a view of a collection using underscores built in templating. (Handlebars is nicer to use though) http://jsfiddle.net/oakley349/hsxfw89b/

Comment: I'm assuming you'd want to make your call based on the item that's clicked.  Here's the same example with a clickhandler on a child of 'el' http://jsfiddle.net/oakley349/hsxfw89b/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to do.
You can run it in this fiddle with some css included: http://jsfiddle.net/oakley349/hsxfw89b/

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="artist-list-template">
    <table> <thead> <tr> <th> Name </th>
        <th>Hometown</th > <th> Favorite Color </th>
    </tr> </thead>
        <tbody>
        <% _.each(events, function(event) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= event.get('ID') %></td>
            <td><%= event.get('EventID') %></td>
            <td><%= event.get('CircuitID') %></td>
            <td><%= event.get('StartTime') %></td>
            <td><%= event.get('EventFormatID') %></td>
            <td><%= event.get('RemainingPlaces') %></td>        
         </tr>
         <% }); %>
        </tbody> </table>
</script>
```

**Backbone/JS**

```
var CalEvent = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'ID',
    defaults: {
        ID: '',
        EventID: '',
        CircuitID: '',
        StartTime: '',
        EventFormatID: '',
        TotalPlaces: '',
        BookedPlaces: '',
        ProvisionalPlaces: ''
    },
    url: '/tracker/booking'
});

var events = [{
    ID: 18,
    EventID: 155957,
    CircuitID: 53,
    StartTime: "2014-11-04 17:15:00",
    EventFormatID: 224,
    RemainingPlaces: 18
}, {
    ID: 56,
    EventID: 123443,
    CircuitID: 23,
    StartTime: "2014-11-04 17:15:00",
    EventFormatID: 224,
    RemainingPlaces: 18
}, {
    ID: 34,
    EventID: 653464,
    CircuitID: 43,
    StartTime: "2014-11-04 17:15:00",
    EventFormatID: 224,
    RemainingPlaces: 18
}];

var CalEvents = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: CalEvent
});

var CalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'body',
    events: {
        'click td': 'clickHandler'
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    clickHandler: function (evt) {
        alert('Clicked ' + evt.currentTarget.textContent);
    },
    render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var template = _.template($('#artist-list-template').html());
        var compiled = template({
            events: that.collection.models
        });
        this.$el.append(compiled);
    }
});
var calView = new CalView({
    collection: new CalEvents(events)
});
```